# LINQ var type cast to List

Tags: c#, list, linq, casting

I've got a method grouping given List with LINQ. I want to output the grouped list with other class. What is the proper way to cast type?

Method:

```
 public List<OutMyFileData> GetGroupedFiles(string path)
{
    // List of all files in given path
    List<MyFileData> allFiles = GetFiles(path);

    return allFiles.OrderBy(file => file.Extension)
                .GroupBy(file => file.Extension)
                .Select(file => new
                {
                    type = file.Key,
                    files = file.Select(ofile => new
                    {
                        ofile.Name,
                        ofile.LastMod,
                        ofile.Size
                    })
                }).ToList() as List<OutMyFileData>;
}
```

And classes:

```
public class MyFileData
{
public string Name { get; set; }

public string LastMod { get; set; }

public long Size { get; set; }

public string Extension { get; set; }
}


public class OutMyFileData
{
public string Name { get; set; }

public string LastMod { get; set; }

public long Size { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with the Extension ? just having a flat list ordered by extension ? (ex : first all the .pdf, then all the .png, etc)

Comment: Extension is used to group the files, but it should not be in the output List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might not return an anonymous object as your result because the type can't be declared for the return type of method.

If I understand correctly, you can try to write a class as return ViewModel `MyFileViewModel` which can contain your return values.

```
public class MyFileViewModel{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OutMyFileData> Files { get; set; }
}
                
public class OutMyFileData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastMod { get; set; }

    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call as below

```
public List<MyFileViewModel> GetGroupedFiles(string path)
{
    List<MyFileData> allFiles = GetFiles(path);

    return allFiles.GroupBy(file => file.Extension)
        .Select(file => new MyFileViewModel()
        {
            Type = file.Key,
            Files = file.Select(ofile => new OutMyFileData()
            {
                Name = ofile.Name,
                LastMod = ofile.LastMod,
                Size = ofile.Size
            })
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to stick to original GetGroupedFiles method type? The method is one out of two used as endpoint in web app, but the second method is OutMyFileData type so the error is thrown about different types